# ng-bootstrap Package mostly incompatible with Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 (i.e. all forms of collapses)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

As a heads up for everybody, most of the current ng-bootstrap package is incompatible with the newest release of bootstrap (Alpha 6), including all collapsing media (collapses, dropdowns, navs, etc.).

I haven't yet found out how to make the package working, I assume that the package is using tags that bootstrap stopped supporting. I suppose we will have to simply wait until the dev changes all the tags, which could take a very long time (bootstrap alpha 6 is basically a re-write...).

If anybody has got a hack to get ng-bootstrap and bootstrap alpha 6 to play nice, let us know!

Comment: I have tested and it doesn't work with Bootstrap 4 too.

Comment: The dev was using a "latest release" import in their Plunkers and most of their plunkers were broken on Friday/Saturday. Seems like they've secretly updated them all to explicitly pull the alpha 5 release now, which made them all work again.

Comment: @SamHughes see https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1178#issuecomment-271285072. Also not sure what you mean by "they've secretly updated" as all the development is very much done in public on GitHub (https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) and all the releases are documented in the CHANGELOG (https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Poor word choice, maybe not "secretly", but still, it isn't stated anywhere on the site, and since there has been enough time to update all Plunkers and etc., surely there was enough time to state it other than on the git?

Comment: @SamHughes where would you suggest to put it on the demo page? The landing page (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/) has the version displayed and https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started clearly states which version of Bootstrap we are testing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) project just released [version 1.0.0-alpha.18](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-alpha18-2017-01-09) with full support for Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6. All the directives are now working with Bootstrap's 4.0.0-alpha.6 CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Does it also support IE11, IE10, and Safari? The grid system is broken in these browser. In Chrome and Firefox, it is compatible.